# Arduino with Figaro TGS sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am going to use few Figaro TGS sensors, which including TGS2600, 2602 and 2620 with my Arduino. I referred to the datasheet and found that these sensors need more than one voltage source. May I know the correct way to connect them to my arduino? (Arduino Mega or Uno probably)...(beginner here)

Comment: Please update your question with links http://www.figarosensor.com/products/entry/tgs2600.html , http://www.figarosensor.com/products/entry/tgs2602.html , http://www.figarosensor.com/products/entry/tgs2620.html and write the voltages that each one needs. What have you read in the datasheet that makes you think that more than one voltage is needed ? I can not find that in the datasheets.

Comment: It needs 5V for the heater and 5V for the detector circuit. What makes you think that is two different voltages? Does 5 not equal 5 in your universe?

Comment: Opps...I made a stupid mistake...So for http://www.figarosensor.com/products/2602pdf.pdf (TGS2602 datasheet), sensor pin 3 and 4 simply connected to the voltage source and pin 1 and 2 simply to the ground (pin 2 with load resistor)...am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. The sensor requires an accurate 5V. That means when you use only a USB cable to power the Arduino and the sensor, the voltage can vary a lot and the result will be unreliable.

Comment: Maybe I can use a 5V voltage regulator

Comment: I think I will use a 9V barrel jack adapter as my power supply...for more stable readings from my sensor

Comment: By the way, I found some information online states that if using 9V barrel jack adapter as my power supply, the use of 5V pin on arduino might overheating the voltage regulator built in...Any suggestion on better way as my power supply? ( I think 9V battery does not provide enough current for the sensors)